# $\sum_{i=0}^N p^i (1-p)^{N-i} , p \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on finding an analytic solution to the [zero-intelligence trader double auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-intelligence_trader). I'm using discrete time continuous state Markov Chains and derive probability density functions. In the end I want to express the average price as a function of the probability of each trader being chosen. For this I need an expression for the two terms

$\sum_{i=0}^N p^i (1-p)^{N-i} , p \in (0,1)$

and

$\sum_{i=0}^N i p^i (1-p)^{N-i} , p \in (0,1)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Which is the actual question? Do you want an analytic result for the two expressions? If so, why should all the details about the Monte Carlo be important?

Comment: Hi Quillo, thanks for asking. I just want an analytic expression for the two equations. Ideally with a proof. I gave the details because my question was closed without the details. Btw, it's not about Monte Carlo but about Markov Chains. But that's just an additional information.

Comment: @Quillo We constantly ask users to provide context on MSE, so the asker is doing just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the finite geometric series formula, and letting $q=1-p$,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^N p^iq^{N-i}=\frac{p^{N+1}/q-q^N}{p/q-1}=\frac{p^{N+1}-q^{N+1}}{p-q}
$$
The second is an [arithmetic-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms). Namely, if $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ is an arithmetic series with difference $d$ and $G_1,G_2,\dots,G_n$ is a geometric series with ratio $r$, then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_kG_k=\frac{A_{n+1}G_{n+1}-A_1G_1}{r-1}+\frac{dr}{(1-r)^2}\cdot (G_{n+1}-G_1)
$$
With your particular parameters, this simplifies to
$$
\sum_{i=0}^N ip^iq^{N-i}=\frac{(N+1)q^{N+1}/p-0}{p/q-1}+\frac{p/q}{(1-p/q)^2}\cdot (q^{N+1}/p-p^N)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot. I see that you're an active member of the community. Thank you for your contributions. Your work is highly appreciated.